# Disable command-enter keyboard shortcut in iTerm2

Tags: macos, keyboard, iterm, shortcut

Currently cmd-enter in iTerm2 toggles fullscreen mode. Is there a way to disable this keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 23):

In iTerm, go to Preferences > Keys, and click the + button at the bottom of the list. There, you can add a new keyboard shortcut for <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↩︎</kbd>, which will by default be ignored.

[image: screenshot of panel]

Comment: FYI as I did this, iTerm asked to earn accessibility privileges. Denying doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: I wish i'd googled this months ago instead of putting up with it, thanks!